# Using webapp2's DomainRoute on google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, routes, subdomain, webapp2

I'm trying to use webapp2's [DomainRoute](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2_extras/routes.html#webapp2_extras.routes.DomainRoute) to route requess to specific users. The definition of the routes looks like this:

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
                                DomainRoute("<subdomain>." + os.environ["HTTP_HOST"], [
                                    webapp2.Route('/',ClientHandler)]),
                            ('/', MainHandler)],
                            debug=True)
```

the handlers all exist, and currently, my ClientHandler should just spit out the current subdomain but when I currently go to nosub.localhost:8090 it doesn't even reach the server. Do I need to edit my hosts file? And if so, is it valid to add a wildcart like *.localhost so any subdomain will work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to edit your hosts file - `whatever.localhost` does not automatically resolve to `127.0.0.1`. Alternately, save yourself some time and use [xip.io](http://xip.io/).

Your code has a significant problem, though: you're using `os.environ["HTTP_HOST"]` in a context that only gets run on the first request. This means that you extract the hostname from the first request to your app and use that as a base name for it and all subsequent requests - which is pretty definitely not what you want. For instance, if the first user to your app instance comes from `subdomain.myapp.com`, you'll set up a route for `subdomain.subdomain.myapp.com`.

Comment: @BillPull Which hostname? At the time your script is run, there's no way for it to know what set of host names it might be accessed at during its lifetime.